# Isolating Swing listener logic for cleaner code

Tags: java, swing, enums, solid-principles

I am trying to keep my Java Swing code clean. I figured one way to do this would be to attempt to isolate listener logic from the rest of the GUI.

What I'm trying to do at the moment is isolate all functionality regarding listeners into a single class/object that exists separately from the main JFrame of the GUI, so that it can be the central place that holds listeners and initiates the logic to assign these to components.

This way, the GUI can be separated into a dumb section (JFrame A contains/displays JPanel B, C, D etc) which holds no logic between how components interact when acted upon, and a smarter section that does hold logic.

Basically, I'm thinking of implementing the following:

- The ListenerAssigner class contains all listeners used in the application as inner classes , instantiates them and hold this as an ArrayList internally. It holds a reference to the JFrame. It is not internal to the JFrame but external to it.
- All listeners will contain an enum value on instantiation. This is will be used to compare itself against the enum value of the object needing a listener.
- The ListenerAssigner calls a custom method on the JFrame (added through an interface) to pass the ArrayList of listeners to the objects that need listeners.
- The JFrame in turn calls a custom method on its internal members to pass down the ArrayList to its internal objects, which in turn they repeat.
- The objects holding the objects that need listeners will then call a findAndSetListener method on the objects, passing the ArrayList into them.
- The objects implement findAndSetListener by iterating through the list of listeners, grabbing their enum values, comparing these against the enum value of the listener, and assigning that listener to itself should they match. We do this through an if statement in a for loop to avoid a very long switch statement.

This way listeners are assigned dynamically and are all contained in a single section instead of being all over different parts of the GUI.

Does this approach seem like a valid one? Would this abide by the SOLID principles and clean methods of coding, or should I just give up on trying to keep listener logic in one place?

Comment: If you really want to reduce coupling, why not consider dependency injection such as may be provided via Spring or Guice? Or go even further with a full fledged MVC framework, such as is found in other components of the Spring framework. Never used them myself, although I've considered using Guice.

Comment: I think you're asking for a lot of pain, as you moving towards a "god" class which is never a good idea. I might consider using a MVC which would help you isolate functionality into distinct functional groups

Comment: Use `Action` to encapsulate functionality, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20Action%20encapsulate).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels After spending the last two weeks learning about Spring, I have found that Spring is perfect for what I'm trying to do, and solves a lot of other problems as well. It's much easier to leverage than to rewrite all of my code. Thank you very much for suggesting it.